# Inject dependencies in the identity controller (account controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I am working in a asp.net mvc application. I use unity for dependency injection. Until now i have injected all the dependencies in UnityConfig.cs(dbcontext, repositories, webservice) and everything is working correctly. Identity framework is added to provide the authentication. I would like to inject some dependencies in the Account Controller, which is the controller used by Identity for the login and register actions, but i can't make it work. Has anyone run into the same problem ?

AccountController.cs

```
public AccountController(IMyRepository myRepository, ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            MyRepository = myRepository;
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }
```

UnityConfig.cs

```
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

Stack Trace

```
    [NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.]
   Assyst.Portail.Controllers.<Register>d__18.MoveNext() in C:\Users\administrateur.ASSYST\Documents\Projets\Portails\Assyst.Portail\Controllers\Identity\AccountController.cs:204
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +125
```

Comment: "but i can't make it work" => what is not working, do you have any errors?

Comment: I have a NullPointerException when i use myRepository, because the first line in UnityConfig uses the parameterless constructor, so it never initializes the repository.

Comment: Please provide us with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question will be closed as "off-topic" without it, because it is impossible for us to answer your question without additional details.

Comment: Than why not initialize it inside your parameterless constructor?

Comment: I have generic repository pattern and the constructor injects all the dependencies. Otherwise I have to create a dbcontext variable and initialize it everytime i use non parameterless constructor.

Comment: Have you registered `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager` with the container? Also, it doesn't appear that you need the `new InjectionConstructor()` parameter. That's for when you have multiple constructors, one is marked with an attribute, and you want to tell the container which constructor to use.